# Python creating a list to find total revenue n times

Tags: python

Total revenue caluculated by increasing price by $5 n times and decreasing customers by 10 n times. here's what I have so far

```
tr = []
startprice = 35
startpeople = 375
def r(num):
    for i in range(num):
        startprice = startprice + 5
        startpeople = startpeople - 10
        revenue = startprice * startpeople
        tr.append(revenue)
    return tr
```

It gives me the error "cannot access local variable 'startprice' where it is not #associated with a value"

Does anyone know how to fix it and make it work? -Thanks

I've tried everything I know. ps. I'm a little new to python

Comment: `startprice` and `startpeople` variables are outside of the scope of your function `r()`. Pass them to your method as arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to pass global variables to your function via the function's  arguments *or* explicitly tell Python you're using global variables.

```
tr = []
startprice = 35
startpeople = 375
def r(num):
    global startprice, startpeople, tr
    for i in range(num):
        startprice = startprice + 5
        startpeople = startpeople - 10
        revenue = startprice * startpeople
        tr.append(revenue)
    return tr
```

Keep in mind that doing this will modify the global variables, whereas if you pass them as arguments, they will be copied, and the global variables unchanged by a run of `r`.

Comment: Is there a way we can close out this question?

Answer (score 1):

`tr`, `startprice` and `startpeople` variables are outside of the scope of your function `r()`.

This can be fixed either by passing them as arguments to your function:

```
startprice = 35
startpeople = 375

def r(num, startprice, startpeople):
    tr = []
    for i in range(num):
        startprice = startprice + 5
        startpeople = startpeople - 10
        revenue = startprice * startpeople
        tr.append(revenue)
    return tr

r(10, startprice, startpeople)
```

Answer (score 0):

An excellent question; the *Python* interpreter defines a *function* *scope* as follows.

*[Python 3.12.0 Documentation – 4.7. Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)*

> *... The execution of a function introduces a new symbol table used for the local variables of the function. More precisely, all variable assignments in a function store the value in the local symbol table; whereas variable references first look in the local symbol table, then in the local symbol tables of enclosing functions, then in the global symbol table, and finally in the table of built-in names. Thus, global variables and variables of enclosing functions cannot be directly assigned a value within a function (unless, for global variables, named in a [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) statement, or, for variables of enclosing functions, named in a [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement), although they may be referenced. ...*

And, here is the relevant *global* keyword documentation.
*[Python 3.12.0 Documentation – 7.12. The global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global)*.

Here is an example.

```py
tr = []
startprice = 35
startpeople = 375
def r(num):
    global startprice, startpeople
    for i in range(num):
        startprice = startprice + 5
        startpeople = startpeople - 10
        revenue = startprice * startpeople
        tr.append(revenue)
    return tr
```